Can't access local Ubuntu server via Wireguard VPN
Looking for a little troubleshooting help accessing my Ubuntu server via a network level Wireguard VPN.
I have Wireguard installed on my PFSense router and assign all connected clients a 192.168.2.0 address. My Ubuntu server sits on my 192.168.54.0 vlan along with several other devices and computers. When I log into my VPN remotely, I can access the other devices (e.g., pikvm, a NAS), but I can't access my Ubuntu server.
Any thoughts on what could be causing this issue? TIA!

routing and firewalling. 192.168.x.0 is traditionally a /24 netmask, .2 and .54 would then need a route to eachother, wireguard may use its own ip range. Also wireguard would need that route configured as an allowedip

Thanks!
Comment above combined with a lot of google searching led me to this post.
Problem seems to be solved by adding the following in my case:
sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.54.1 metric 0

